# Fixed rendered text size in 3D animation

Tags: animation, edit-mode

I made a 3D animation with some camera moves, rotations and changes of orthographic scale.
I would like to render some pieces of text that would "follow" each 3D objects, but I would like to have all the texts with a constant defined size during all the animation (no increase / decrease of text size).

---

### I have tried the following methods:

**1) Render object and text separately and use VFX trackers to match text to object.**
It would consist to :

- render objects without text
- render some "dummy" spheres on the same locations than objects
- use VFX to track the spheres
- associate some empties to the tracks
- parent some text to the empties
- combine in VSE the render of the objects and the render of the text in a final render

This method works but is not very efficient.

---

**2) Render object and use VSE_Transform_Tools to track and associate text.**

It's similar to case 1 but tracking can be done directly in the VSE via the VSE_Transform_Tools plugin:

- render the object
- render some "dummy" spheres on the same locations than the objects
- use VFX in the VSE to track the "dummy" spheres and create some empties
- create the text in the VSE
- link the text to the empties via the VSE_Transform_Tools plugin
- make the final render in the VSE

For unknown reasons, the text rendered by this method has a very very low quality

---

**3) Try to link the text size directly into the 3D animation to the orthographic value of the camera:**

- Insert the text directly into the main 3D animation
- Use a Copy Rotation Constraint to have always the text parallel to the camera
- adapt the text scale with some key frames in order to match the orthographic scale
- render all at once

I didn't manage to adapt properly the text scale to the orthographic value of the camera. Is it possible to do it via a driver or other ?

---

Are there some better ways to proceed, like for example exporting some empties coordinates placed into the initial 3D scene animation into a 2D scene in order to directly link some 2D scene empties to the text and avoid to go thru the VFX tracking process ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RobinBets are you interested, ideas for 3rd option? To drive Text object size by Camera's Orthographic Scale parametr to keep text constant from camera view. Thanks you